# How can I make VSCode recognize structural pattern matching (match case) with Python3.10?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

So I am using Python3.10rc2 (Py3.10 is not officially released yet), and I want the match case statement to be highlighted, or at least not have error squiggly lines show up. Somehow I did not have a problem with this before in VScode when using Py3.10 (maybe I was using a slightly earlier 3.10 beta version?). But now I seem to be getting error squiggly lines when I write this statement. Does anybody have an idea how I can fix this?

[image]

Cheers.

Comment: What's the error message of the linter or language server prompt?

Comment: @Steven-MSFT It was something with jedi indententation error. However, I've somehow managed to make it work again after reinstalling the Python extension.

Answer (score 0):

update Pylance to Pre-release and restart VS Code